# I have a problem with installing intel HAXM

Tags: android

So umm I recently having problem with running emulator so I tried to install Intel HAXM. But it failed because my CPU is not Intel's...

1. Is there no way to run emulator unless I change my CPU???
2. Actually I am using my smartphone device connected instead of emulator. Is there no difference between using emulator and real smartphone device??
3. As I mentioned above, I can't install HAXM.. Can it make or imply the problem during running Android Studio or coding/ making app???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAXM can only be used with Intel CPUs.

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows) the path is clear:

> Though we recommend using HAXM on Windows, it is possible to use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) with the emulator. You should use WHPX with the emulator if you are using an AMD CPU or if you need to use Hyper-V at the same time.

Note: AFAIK WHPX requires Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise or Education. Therfeore with a Windows 10 Home you will not be able to run a hardware accelerated Android emulator.

Of course you can still run Android ARM and x86 emulator images, but not with hardware acceleration. Therefore the emulator will behave much slower.

Comment: So there  is no problem with coding or creating app?? Cause I can use my real device

Comment: @백근우 AXM is only for the emulator. Everything else is totally independent of HAXM.

Comment: Yeah I meant my third question. Anyway thankyou about it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh wait you said I can still run emulator with WHPS or HAXM, but Compiler AVD says I can't run virtual device without hardware accelerator

Comment: @백근우 You need emulation technology in your CPU. If the emulator complains about it usually it is simply disabled in the BIOS. Check the same of the virtualization technology of your cpu, search for it in the BIOS and enable it.